# Where to start Transcoding with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding, mp4

I would like to learn a lot about Transcoding video files with FFMPEG from any format to mp4 (hH264/AAC) format. We have a large repository of video files ranging from 1 MB to 2 GB of various formats like mkv,mp4,avi,wmv,mov,m4a etc including both HD and SD.

After converting we will be uploading the files to a CDN from where we stream it through JW player.

So, the goal here was to attain a maximum quality with reasonable file size and has to stream faster.

I am planning to use FFMPEG for transcoding.

Please point me to the articles where I could learn about efficient transcoding.

Comment: This is really kind of a loaded question.  There are companies whose sole business is encoding/transcoding.  We might be able to direct you towards some introductory resources, but you are jumping in to a very deep, very detailed field that can be done as simply as using presets for your format and resolution or as complex as custom encodings fine tuned for individual videos relying on in depth knowledge of the codec being used.

Comment: A good start would be the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide). You can add `-movflags faststart` to your ffmpeg command so the videos can be viewed by the client as they are being downloaded.

Comment: @AJHenderson Yes, I've worked with Mediacoder, Handbrake and few other tools, but my vision here is to learn and use FFMPEG and deign my own transcoder